# force stop scrolling on reaching the end of a scrollspy section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[here is a fiddle to know where I am starting from](http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/rWYQu/)

The problem I am looking to solve involves "paginating" content of a single html file, in such a way that locks them into a single section at a time. I want it so that when users scroll to the bottom of a section, it will slide up a prompt to move to the next page, which will [fire a transition, such as different easing/from bottom](http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/) and put them "in" the next section.

This would be repeated in the next section; when they scroll to the top, they will get a "previous" button but be unable to move unless they click "previous". If they hit the bottom, they will be unable to move to the next page without clicking "next". If they click a section tab, it would do the transition and bring them to that page from their current

I know that this will stop scrolling, but how do I modify it such that it will prevent scrolling *in this way*?

```
$('body').on({
'mousewheel': function(e) {
    if (e.target.id == 'el') return;
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    }
})
```

Comment: `preventDefault()` is the only thing you need to run -- it implicitly calls `stopPropagation()` and is cross-browser-consistent

Comment: oh okay, to be quite honest I stole this from another stack overflow question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just have the window continue to scroll back to the element by using `window.scrollTo`.

I get the top bottom position and the height of the element, and then when the element is in view of the window I `scollTo` the difference between the window `innerHeight` and the elements position.

```
var el = document.querySelector('.stop');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
    var elementPos = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
        elBot = elementPos.bottom,
        elHeight = elementPos.height,
        curTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop; 

    if(elBot <= window.innerHeight-elHeight){
         window.scrollTo(0,curTop-(window.innerHeight - elBot));
    }
});
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/46pK6/2)**

[And a more complete example with clicking to move on, just to illustrate further.](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/46pK6/)